# iOS main view is responding to subview gestures

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I'm adding subviews with tap gestures:

from UIView class(masterButton):

> ```
> [self addSubview:self.button];
>
> // Add gesture recognizers
> [self addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(isTapped:)]];
> ```

ViewController:

> masterButton *button = [[masterButton alloc] initWithFrontImage:img
>   ];
>
> [self.view addSubview:button];

I removing the subview:

> UIView * button= [controller.view  viewWithTag:controller.tagButton];
>           [button removeFromSuperview];

The tap gesture it triggers to play audio file and works just fine but when I remove the subview and I tap the same area where the subview was it plays the audio like if the subview was there. How can I add the subview in a way were the main view is not responding to any gesture of the subviews?

I'm generating the subviews from UIview subclass and if I try to add the gesture like this:

> [self.button addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
>   initWithTarget:self action:@selector(isTapped:)]];

it doesn't work. any of you knows why?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: How are you removing the subview. Post your code

Comment: as your code shows you are adding gesturerecognizer to your view i think you should add it to your subview(button).[self.button addGestureRecognizer:.......];      [self.view add subview:self.button];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add button like

```
[self.button addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(isTapped:)]]

[self.button removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding UITapGestureRecognizer to the mainview

Add UITapGestureRecognizer to `self.button` instead of `self`

```
[self.button addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(isTapped:)]];
[self addSubview:self.button];
```

Comment: The problem is not removing the subview. the problem is the main view responding to the tap gestures

Answer (score 0):

just add Gesture to the masterButton like bellow..

```
[self.button addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(isTapped:)]];
```